# Anyone implemented Android Backup Service with android:backupAgent?

Tags: android, backup, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In Android 6 it looks like Google has finally got its automatic backup service to include pretty much all app data in it's backups to a nominated Google account as long as android:targetSdkVersion="23".

However in versions of Android prior to 6, as I understand it, you need to implement a custom BackupAgent in order to include specific files into the Backup Service such as app-generated files and databases.

How might I achieve this in Appcelerator, would a custom module be required along with new entries in the Android section of tiapp.xml?

http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html
http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html#previous-androids

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs it seems all of this is configured via your `AndroidManifest.xml` (configurable via `tiapp.xml` in Titanium) and `res/xml` files (stored under `app/platform/android` in Alloy 1.8+). So you should be able to use this with Appcelerator Titanium.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on this. I figured that would work with Android 6, but if you look at this: [Android Developer link](http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html#previous-androids) regarding supporting previous versions of Android, it says you need to use the Backup API along with a BackupAgent, which looks to be custom Java code?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. It's hard to say if that could be done in a Titanium module. It might be a good idea to create a JIRA ticket requesting for this to be researched, also as a way to achieve parity with iCloud backup of files for iOS.